# Android toolbar icon handling with SQLite

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-menu

I need hint to setup toolbar menu. How to change toolbar icon automatically when an Intent is open. I am using SQLite to save data for bookmarked posts. If user already bookmarked the post then toolbar icon will be change else icon will be same.

[image]

Let's take an example, in this image here is a bookmark button (Star) when I clicked on it data will save in Bookmark table. After that I Closed that post. Now I again open that post which is bookmarked but this time their is change in toolbar menu icon like this :

[image]

To perform this function data is loaded from bookmark table.

In my app no need to hold a post and show this toolbar. When someone click on post an intent is open. Toolbar of that intent will used for this functionality. Toolbar of post is [here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWMF5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWMF5.png) and selected icon will change when clicked by user. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found solution :** initialize an `int` before `onCreate` like this :

```
int bkmark;
```

than in `onCreate` get data from `SQLite` before initializing toolbar and check is this post is bookmarked or not.

if data is available

```
bkmark = 1;
```

else

```
bkmark = 0;
```

In `onCreateOptionsMenu` I am using two menu like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    if(bkmark == 0){//bkmark is not available
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.posts, menu);
    }else{//bkmark is available
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.postb, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

In `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id==R.id.bkm){
         if(bkmark == 1){
             //delete data from bookmark table here
             item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmark);//changing the icon
             bkmark = 0;
         }else{
             //insert data in bookmark table here
             item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmarked);//changing the icon
             bkmark = 1;
         }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope this post help you if you are looking something like this !